Weekly Topic Challenge: Let's ask about Version Bits (BIP9)‽
This week signaling for Segregated Witness will commence. The activation process for soft forks follows the rules set in BIP9: Version Bits.
There has been some confusion about the activation process, the exact date when signaling begins, and other details of BIP9. 
Currently, we have seven questions about Version Bits, let's ask and learn! 
Please use version-bits to tag your questions, and consider asking any questions about the activation process, the timeframe, what happens when multiple proposals are open, or whatever else you want to know about it.
This weekly topic challenge runs until 2016-11-24. Happy posting!

This week, no questions were asked about Version Bits. :(
